# dataframe flatten array value column to columns

Tags: python, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,1], [10,1]]), np.array([[11,1],[12,1],[13,1],[20,1]]), np.array([[11,1],[13,1],[14,1],[20,1]])], 'label' : ['a', 'a', 'b']})
print (df)
```

I want to flatten array valued column 'Data'  to  2*4 = 8 columns, say 'col_1',...,'col_8'. We can guarantee the shape of array of each cell in 'Data' is same (but regard shape of array as dynamic, do not use the specific number)

Comment: You should do this conversion in `numpy` BEFORE taking it into `pandas`. Flattening rows is pretty easy in `numpy`.

Comment: @TimRoberts I know how to use .flatten(), but don't know how to assign to columns with dynamic number, say create len(x.flatten()) columns

Comment: When you create a dataframe, you pass a `columns` array that has the list of file names.  You can create those using normal string formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do dynamically by getting length of array. Once get length you can set number of columns and set array values inside the column by pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,1], [10,1]]), np.array([[11,1],[12,1],[13,1],[20,1]]), np.array([[11,1],[13,1],[14,1],[20,1]])], 'label' : ['a', 'a', 'b']})

# Determine the number of columns from array
num_columns = df['Data'][0].size

# Create column names
column_names = [f'col_{i+1}' for i in range(num_columns)]

# Apply the flattening
flattened_columns = df['Data'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.flatten(), index=column_names))

# Concatenate the original DataFrame with the flattened columns
df = pd.concat([df.drop('Data', axis=1), flattened_columns], axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: clear answer! those values will be used to get a scalar by np.tensordot('Data', x) i.e. product on corresponding elements then sum together. here x has the same shape with the element of 'Data'. So do you think which one is better? store in one column as a high-dimensional array or flatten as a large number of columns?

Comment: You can do whatever takes less time for process. But I think you can use large number of columns because it is easy for debug the df if you have any problems in next step.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a python one-liner for you:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [np.array([[1,1], [2,2], [3,1], [10,1]]), np.array([[11,1],[12,1],[13,1],[20,1]]), np.array([[11,1],[13,1],[14,1],[20,1]])], 'label' : ['a', 'a', 'b']})
>>> pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(df['Data'].apply(np.ravel).to_list(), columns=['col'+str(i) for i in range(1,9)])], axis=1).drop(columns='Data')
  label  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6  col7  col8
0     a     1     1     2     2     3     1    10     1
1     a    11     1    12     1    13     1    20     1
2     b    11     1    13     1    14     1    20     1
```